# How do I inject html elements using jquery based on a given number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, code-injection

I am using jquery to get a count of children elements within a parent div.

```
$('#slideshow > div').size()
```

Then using `append()`, I'd like to inject the number of div elements that are in `#slideshow` into another div called `.mainImageBrowserTabButtonWrapper`

Any help on this would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I realize my initial question didn't describe what I wanted very well.

Lets say I have the number of elements in `#slideshow` is 3. I would then like to inject 3 other divs into `.mainImageBrowserTabButtonWrapper`

Comment: Do you want to move all the divs from `#slideshow` to `.mainImageBrowserTabButtonWrapper`? Or do you just want to write the number as text inside the buttonWrapper div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could clone the elements.

```
$("#slideshow > div").clone().appendTo(".mainImageBrowserTabButtonWrapper");
```

Or, if you'd prefer brand new, empty elements you could use a loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < $("#slideshow > div").length; i++)
    $(".mainImageBrowserTabButtonWrapper").append("<div />");
```

Comment: why is it that 90% of the time the solution is so simple? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.mainImageBrowserTabButtonWrapper').text(  $('#slideshow > div').size() )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the count separately and append it on the next call:

```
var count = $("#slideshow > div").size();
$(".mainImageBrowserTabButtonWrapper").text( "Count: " + count );
```

Note: This only shows the count, it doesn't clone the divs.